# misspecified models coverage and efficiency

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model, efficiency, misspecification, coverage-probability

Suppose I have model $M$ generating data $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\beta_2Z+\beta_3W$ with all $\beta$'s known. Instead of using model $M$, I used misspecified models $M':Y=\beta'_0+\beta'_1X+\beta'_2Z$, $M'':Y=\beta'_0+\beta'_1X+\beta'_3W$ and went on testing hypothesis $H_0:\beta'_1=0$ vs $H_1:\beta'_1\neq 0$ with level $\alpha$ for $M'$ and $M''$.

$Q1:$ Should this hypothesis testing inversion give a coverage of $1-\alpha$ in general? The inversion of testing to get confidence interval requires model specification correctness assumption. If the model is correctly specified, then $coverage+level$ would be 1. If not, I could not see why it should even be the case. Level $\alpha$ is always fixed number, but coverage could be $0$ due to bias.

$Q2:$ Should I even compare efficiency between $M'$ and $M''$ for estimating $\beta'_1$? It could be possible that one of the models having efficiency$>1$. This does not fit into unbiased estimator's Cramer-Rao bound context. What does it mean to even compare $M'$ and $M''$'s $\beta'_1$'s efficiency or confidence interval width here?